# best way to assign variable length strings to list elements in python3.4

Tags: python, string, list, element

I have a text file that has a variable length of digits ('62554' could be 'xxxx' or 'xxx')

```
# cat dsset-domain.com.
domain.com.          IN DS 62554 8 1 84988C2B6D3C92F35E1457D3771D0270417622D2
domain.com.          IN DS 62554 8 2 EF940E2D5CFAD8B47A699ACCD68A77C43F120774CABCCA5A25443BE3 1D1BEABF
```

I need the last 4 strings of the first line assigned to list variables:

```
list[0] = 62554
list[1] = 8
list[2] = 1
list[3] = 84988C2B6D3C92F35E1457D3771D0270417622D2
```

But I don't exactly have a delimiter to work with.

What is the best way to slice up a line of strings of variable length and assign them as list elements?

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import string
import requests

name = input("Enter the domain to provision DS keys for? ")
url = 'https://www.provider.net/ws/domain/'+name+'/ds'


with open('/usr/local/etc/namedb/dsset-'+name+'.', 'rt') as in_file:
        dstext = in_file.read()
print(dstext)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `split` ant pickup the last 3 item with slicing :

```
>>> s="domain.com.          IN DS 62554 8 1 84988C2B6D3C92F35E1457D3771D0270417622D2"
>>> s.split()[-3:]
['8', '1', '84988C2B6D3C92F35E1457D3771D0270417622D2']
```

Comment: it says I have to wait 9 min to click the button. Thank you!

Comment: but he wants to get the values only from the first line.

Comment: @AvinashRaj So OP can apply this just on first line! ;)

Comment: @Kasra   specifically ->  dslist = dstext.split()[3:7]   got it. But your concept worked and no loop required.

Comment: @mine yeah! surely! actually always there are more that 1 way to figure out the programming problems, but the winner is the faster!

Comment: You forgot to provide a link to split functions documentation

Answer (score 0):

`fileobject.readline` function will fetch only the first line.

```
with open('file') as f:
    l = []
    m = f.readline().split()
    l = m[-4:]
    print(l)
```

Output:

```
['62554', '8', '1', '84988C2B6D3C92F35E1457D3771D0270417622D2']
```